# SilverStripe Gridfield how to remove buttons

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have been going through the gridfield class documentation here;
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/reference/grid-field

Here is the code in question. While it does display a grid-field it adds a button on each columns. How would I edit this code to not display the buttons? The buttons are links to a non-existent page. 
Link to rendered page; http://www.silverstripe.org/assets/Uploads/Capture28.JPG

```
public function AllPages() {
$gridField = new GridField('pages', 'All pages', SiteTree::get()); 
$dataColumns = $gridField->getConfig()->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns');
$dataColumns->setDisplayFields(array(
    'Title' => 'Title',
    'URLSegment'=> 'URL',
    'LastEdited' => 'Changed'
));
return new Form($this, "AllPages", new FieldList($gridField), new FieldList());
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The cause:**

The SilverStripe GridField is pretty well built.
The Basic GridField has pretty much no features at all. Its just a plain table containing the data you want.
All other functionality is added by so called "Components" which are managed by the GridFieldConfig.

When you create a GridField like you did, without specifying a config, it will Create a config for you (`GridFieldConfig_Base`).

The class `GridFieldConfig_Base` is just a normal `GridFieldConfig` with some components already added.
One of those components that is already added for you is called the `GridFieldSortableHeader` which allows you to press on fields to sort the table (which is what produces those buttons that you see).
The reason the Links of the Buttons are dead is probably because there is some routing problem (The GridField is not that well tested in FrontEnd yet) or you maybe have forgotten to add the action `AllPages` to `$allowed_actions`.

---

**Solutions:**

1. **Plain table**
   if you don't really need any feature of GridField, and you just want a plain table, the easiest way is to just set an empty config:

   ```
   public function AllPages() {
       $config = GridFieldConfig::create(); 
       $dataColumns = GridFieldDataColumns::create();
       $dataColumns->setDisplayFields(array(
           'Title' => 'Title',
           'URLSegment'=> 'URL',
           'LastEdited' => 'Changed'
       ));
       $config->addComponent($dataColumns);
       $gridField = GridField::create('pages', 'All pages', SiteTree::get(), $config); 
       return Form::create($this, __FUNCTION__, FieldList::create($gridField), FieldList::create());
    }
   ```
2. **Remove just the Sortable Header**

   ```
   $gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldSortableHeader');
   // if you don't have a SortableHeader, you probably also don't want a filter
   $gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldFilterHeader');
   ```
3. **Replace the Sortable Header with a text only header row**

   Unfortunately, there is no normal header in SilverStripe at this time, but the great gridfieldextensions module from Andrew Short brings you one.
   Get the module on [GitHub](https://github.com/ajshort/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions) or [Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/ajshort/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions)

   ```
   $gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldSortableHeader');
   // if you don't have a SortableHeader, you probably also don't want a filter
   $gridField->getConfig()->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldFilterHeader');
   $gridField->getConfig()->addComponent(new GridFieldTitleHeader());
   ```
4. **fix the Sortable Header**
   if you wish to have the sort functionality, you will have to fix the routing.
   It has been a while since I last used the GridField in frontend. I can only tell you that it did work at some time.

   1. perhaps routing does not work because your form action (`AllPages`) is not accessible as URL, if that's the case, its pretty easy to fix: just add `AllPages` to your `$allowed_actions` of your Controller.
   2. if the form is accessible, then its probably a bug in GridField, I would need to debug that to tell you any more. If that is the case, please reply via comment or contact me on IRC and I will take a look at it.

UPDATE: I just answered another frontend GridField question, and went a bit more in depth. perhaps this is also helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22433159/1119263 (see Option 2)

Comment: this could help you to have Gridfield working on Frontend:
http://addons.silverstripe.org/add-ons/webbuilders-group/silverstripe-frontendgridfield

Comment: very useful link indeed, if you want GridField features like the detail view in frontend, it will help a lot. however, it will not solve the SortableHeader problems.

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Looks like SilverStripe,

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Looks like SilverStripe, Doesn't like this line.   'code' $dataColumns = GridFieldDataColumns()::create(); But your example works if I create the dataColumns like this. $dataColumns = new GridFieldDataColumns(); I am going to try and play with option 4 when I get some more time. The URL is not accessible. I guess I am not sure why you need access the page to sort the columns.

Comment: ah, my mistake, its suppose to be `GridFieldDataColumns::create();` instead of `GridFieldDataColumns()::create();`. fixed it in the answer. `GridFieldDataColumns::create();` is similar to `new GridFieldDataColumns();` with the difference that it runs some SilverStripe magic in the process of creating a new object (Injector).

Comment: `why you need access the page to sort the columns.` - well, let me put it like this: in order to sort the grid, the GridField needs to talk to the server, because sorting is done server side. Obviously it can't be some random URL, the server needs to know which GridField it is, on which Page, with which Items in it. So the way SilverStripe handles that is by generating the URL like this: `/pageURL/FormName/field/GridFieldName`, this way, if the GridField sends a request, the server knows exactly which GridField it is.

Comment: However, for security reasons, SilverStripe blocks all URLs that are not white-listed. So you need to add this URL to the white-list to let SilverStripe know you want it to route this request through. Or if its not a security related problem, it is probably some other bug related to routing in GridField.